# Product of $\limsup_{x\to\infty} x_n $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf

Given $x_n > 0$ and
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} x_n \cdot \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{x_n} = 1$$
Does this mean that $x_n$ converges?

Comment: Do you anything to say by yourself?

Comment: I want to assume that $x_n$ does not have a limit and then come to contradiction.

Comment: Good plan. Hint: $\limsup 1/x_n= 1/\liminf x_n$.

Comment: Assume $x_n$ has no limit. Then $\limsup x_n \neq \liminf x_n$. As you mentioned $\limsup 1/x = 1/\liminf x$, so i have $\limsup x_n \cdot \frac{1}{\liminf x_n} = 1 \Rightarrow \limsup x_n = \liminf x_n$. So we came to contradiction here, so our initial assumption was incorrect, then $x_n$ converges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. With $x_n>0,$ as stated. Let  $r=\lim \sup_{n\to \infty}.$ Then $r>0.$

(   because $r\geq 0$ and $\lim \sup_{n\to \infty}(1/x_n)\geq 0$ and $r\cdot \lim \sup_{n\to \infty}(1/x_n)=1.$).

Suppose $(x_n)_n$ does not converge to $r$. Then for some $s>0$ there are infinitely many $n$ for which $|x_n-r|>s.$ But there are only finitely many $n$ for which $x_n-r>s,$ else $r=\lim \sup_{n\to \infty} x_n\geq r+s>r,$ an absurdity.

So there are infinitely many $n$ for which $0<x_n<r-s .$ But that implies $\lim \sup_{n\to \infty}(1/x_n)\geq 1/(r-s)>1/r,$ a contradiction.